# CSS only - transition from auto to auto

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a div transition from one auto height to another when the content of that div changes?

Ex:
I have a div with `height: auto;` and that div contains ten rows of text. Can I transition the height of that div if I add/remove ex. 5 rows (and still have that height set to auto)?

Comment: Can you please make an example. I have no clue what you exactly want.

Comment: very closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Answer (score -1):

It is... BUT!

In CSS, you can't transition a `height: auto` to another `height: auto` you HAVE to provide 2 values to transition between them. However, we can achieve - nearly - the same effect using `padding!`.

```js
let textContainer = document.querySelector(".content")

// Hover to change the content
textContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  textContainer.innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum<br> is simply dummy text<br> of the printing and typesetting<br>"
  textContainer.classList.toggle("animated")
})

// Back to its normal
textContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  textContainer.innerHTML = "Dummy Content</br>Another Line..."
  textContainer.classList.toggle("animated")
})
```

```css
.content {
  width: 150px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.animated {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Dummy Content<br>
  Another Line...
</div>
```

To get the best result, you can manipulate the following:

- `padding`
- `transition-timing-function`

This is probably the cleanest way to achieve what you need!

*NOTE: There is no need to use `height: auto` as we don't rely on it.*

Comment: I wonder why I got downvoted? So that I can improve my answers next time!

Comment: Well, if that downvote because of using `JavaScript` code and the question need `CSS Only` solution... I used the JS to simulate the `mouseover` and `mouseout` effects and add some text to that box.

But, the CSS only is all about adding that `.animated` class - for example; when hovering!